# Longer footnoterule on continuing footnote

Tags: footnotes

In a document typeset with LuaLaTeX I have a `footnoterule` defined thus

```
\def\footnoterule{
    \kern -3.25pt
    \hrule height .25pt depth 0pt width .5\hsize
    \kern 3pt
}
```

i.e. its length is half of the text width. However now I am requested to make a change for couple of really long foot notes, going over two or more pages, so that *continuation* of such a foot note starts with the rule ¾ of the text width long (`.75\hsize`).

I've tried package `footmisc` and it works for a simple test case however it does nothing in my document (I suppose it clashes with some other package or so; the document is large, over thousand pages, and uses a lot of other packages and custom macros).

I have not the slightest idea where to start with this, so any advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can test if `\box\fotins` begins with a glue or not in `\output` routine. If it does not begins with a glue then normal footnote is at the top of footnotes. Else it begins by glue from `\splittopskip` and this is the signal that the continuation of a footnote is at the top of footnotes in this page.

The implementation could be:

```
\newif\ifnextfoot

\def\testcontinuefoot{
   \setbox0=\vbox{\unvcopy\footins
   \loop
       \global\dimen0=\lastskip
       \unskip\unskip\unpenalty
       \setbox0=\lastbox
       \unless\ifvoid0 
   \repeat
   }
   \ifdim\dimen0=0pt \nextfootfalse \else \nextfoottrue \fi
}
\def\footnoterule{
   \kern -3.25pt
   \hrule height .25pt depth 0pt width 
       \ifnextfoot.75\else.5\fi \hsize  % .75 or .5 \hsize
   \kern 3pt
}
\output={\testcontinuefoot \plainoutput}
```

Of course, my code is applicable for plain TeX, no for LaTeX. You mentioned LuaLaTeX, i.e. my code is not directly usable for your needs. But the idea can be used.